# Track objects in OpenCV from incoming MJPEG Stream

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mjpeg

I have been successful in capturing a mjpeg stream from my device using mjpeg-streamer. The following code is how I retrieve this stream in OpenCV-python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib

stream=urllib.urlopen('http://@192.168.7.2:8090/?action=stream/frame.mjpg')
bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('i',i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

I also have code that tracks moving objects based on their color range. The video source for this code was pulled directly from the webcam natively in OpenCV. This is the code:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import time
import sys

capture = CaptureFROMCAM(0)

while True:
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)


cv.Smooth(img,img,cv.CV_BLUR,3)
hue_img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8, 3)
cv.CvtColor(img,hue_img, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)

# Remove all the pixels that don't match
threshold_img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(hue_img), 8, 1)
cv.InRangeS(hue_img, (100,180,80), (225,160,80), threshold_img)

# Find all the areas of color out there
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contour = cv.FindContours(threshold_img, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Step through all the areas
points = []
while contour:
    # Get the info about this area
    rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contour))
    contour = contour.h_next()
    # Check to make sure the area is big enough to be of concern
    size = (rect[2] * rect[3])
    if size > 25:
        pt1 = (rect[0], rect[1])
        pt2 = (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1]+rect[3])
        # Add a rectangle to the initial image
        cv.Rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, (15,15,255))    

threshold_img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(hue_img),8,1)
cv.InRangeS(hue_img, (16,82,19), (30,255,255), threshold_img)

cv.ShowImage("Color Tracking", img)
cv.ShowImage("threshold", threshold_img)    

if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
    success, frame = videoCapture.read()
    while success:
        videoWriter.write(frame)
        success, frame = videoCapture.read()
    break
```

**My question is:** How can I combine the two processes so that I can use the decoded jpeg images done by the first program as the input for the image processing in the second code? I have tried all sorts of combinations but I'm still not having any luck. I keep receiving the error

> cv.QueryFrame has has no valid argument 'capture'

This tells me that it's not liking the jpeg format that i'm trying to feed it. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The key idea of connecting both algorithms:

```
#infinite loop
#...stream reading operations
if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
    jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
    bytes= bytes[b+2:]
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
        exit(0) 
else:
    continue
cv.Smooth(img,img,cv.CV_BLUR,3)
#... other tracker operations ...
```

The imdecode function "reads an image from a buffer in memory". QueryFrame reads data from a video capturing device and returns also an image. ("Grabs, decodes and returns the next video frame.") So both these methods give you an image object but each of them from a different source (camera vs. buffer). And an image is the right thing you need for further processing in the tracker! The majority of OpenCV methods use an image as their intrinsic raster data format.

The pipeline than is like this: capture frame/load picture from an image file or a video->[image]-> processing, calculations, thresholds, contours etc. done on the image -> display results or a modified image -> repeat this (forever :-)). See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html for more information.

Comment: OP & @karlphilip Hi thank you for your replies. I tried this method and was told by openCV that img needs to be and openCVMat and to use cv.fromarray() to do this. So this is what I ended up with: `cv.fromarray((img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)), allowND=False)` This only shows one image then it freezes. I would think it would continously convert the image as it is captured but it either seems to only capture one image or it freezes. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Examining the first source code, when `cv2.imshow('i',i)` is executed the webcam image is displayed on a window.

At this point, **instead of displaying the image you should process it with the algorithm** from the second code, which starts after `img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)`. What this means is that you don't need these lines anymore:

```
capture = CaptureFROMCAM(0)

while True:
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```